# comparing generic type E node objects

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree, comparable

I have a class

```
private class BSTNode<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<E> {
    BSTNode<E> left, right;
    E data;
```

with constructor and compairTo method

but when I want instantiate the BSTNode class I face problem.

```
public class BST {
private BSTNode<E> root;

/* Constructor */
public BST() {
    root = new BSTNode<E>();
}
```

how should I use BSTNode in my BST class ? Thanks

Comment: it first suggests add E type argument to BST --> BST<E> and when I do that it says :  Bound mismatch: The type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable<E>> of the type BST<E>.BSTNode<E>

Comment: You need to specify that E i.e. say an MyClass which implements comparable or else make BST generic as well.

Comment: @almasshaikh yes I want to make the BST generic as well , but how ?

Answer (score 1):

Something on these lines (not full fledge or concrete):

```
public class BST<E extends Comparable<E>> 
{
  private class BSTNode<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<E> {
  BSTNode<E> left, right;
  E data;
  @Override
  public int compareTo(E o) {
    return 0;//implement method here
  }
 }
 private BSTNode<E> root;
 public BST() {
   root = new BSTNode<E>();//while comparing you would need to case E to comparable and call compareTo method
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    BST<String> messages = new BST<String>();
 }
}
```

Comment: at least errors disappeared , I will test the correctness a bit later. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your class header means that your BTSNode may only be instantiated with classes E which implement the Comparable interface.

As such, you should be able to use it as below:

```
public class BST {
    private BSTNode<Integer> root;

    /* Constructor */
    public BST() {
        root = new BSTNode<Integer>();
    }
}
```

`Integer` may be replaced with any of the other implementing classes listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or your even own custom implementation.